# How to zoom an image based on current zoom position in xamarin ios

Tags: xamarin.ios, uiimageview, zooming

I have used UIPinchGestureRecgonizer to zoom an image. Everytime when scaling occurs, the image gets zoom from its center position instead of current zoom position. How to zoom an image based on a point instead of center?

```
UIImageView view;
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            view = new UIImageView();
            view.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
            view.Image = UIImage.FromFile("world.png");
            view.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(10, 20, 256, 256);
            UIPinchGestureRecognizer gesture = new UIPinchGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture);
            view.AddGestureRecognizer(gesture);
            View.Add(view);
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        private void pinchGesture(UIPinchGestureRecognizer pinchGestureRecgonizer)
        {
            pinchGestureRecgonizer.View.Transform *= CoreGraphics.CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(pinchGestureRecgonizer.Scale,
                                                                                                      pinchGestureRecgonizer.Scale);
            pinchGestureRecgonizer.Scale = 1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this documentation about [AnchorPoint](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/CocosSharp.CCLabelBMFont.AnchorPoint/), we know that change its value to modify one control's transform point. Since its default value is (0.5,0.5), the control will always scale at center position.

Firstly, let the UIImageView allow multiple touch then we can calculate the `AnchorPoint`. Here I let it be the center of two fingers：

```
view.MultipleTouchEnabled = true;

// Calculate it in the touch began event
public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
{
    base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);

    if (touches.Count == 2)
    {
        UITouch firstTouch = touches.ToArray<UITouch>()[0];
        UITouch secondTouch = touches.ToArray<UITouch>()[1];

        var firstPoint = firstTouch.LocationInView(view);
        var secondPoint = secondTouch.LocationInView(view);

        var centerPoint = new CoreGraphics.CGPoint((firstPoint.X + secondPoint.X) / 2, (firstPoint.Y + secondPoint.Y) / 2);
        view.Layer.AnchorPoint = new CoreGraphics.CGPoint(centerPoint.X / 256, centerPoint.Y / 256);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using anchor point does not resolve the issue. Is there any other way to proceed?